# How to fill color polygon with extra line in GeoJSON layer?

Tags: android, polygon, geojson

I am a beginner with GeoJson layer in android. I want to draw polygons with filling some color on GeoJson layer. The problem is that I can't fill color in polygon with extra line on GeoJson layer.

Here is my code.

```
 heatMapLayer = GeoJsonLayer(map,  [2]JSONObject(Gson().toJson(featureCollection)))
        heatMapLayer?.features?.forEach {
            var colorIndex = it.getProperty("temp").toDouble().toInt()
            if (colorIndex < -10) {
                colorIndex = -10
            }
            if (colorIndex > 40) {
                colorIndex = 40
            }
            val polygonStyle = GeoJsonPolygonStyle()
            polygonStyle?.fillColor = Utils.hex2ARgb(170, Constants.heatMapColor[colorIndex] ?: error(""))
            polygonStyle?.strokeWidth = 0f
            it.polygonStyle = polygonStyle
            val pointStyle = GeoJsonPointStyle()
            pointStyle.isDraggable = true
            it.pointStyle = pointStyle
        }
```

I want to show all polygons with colors.

Here is sample GeoJson data.

{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "temp": 28.0,
        "defaultUnit": "Â°C"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              106.70791799658124,
              10.575534789370789
            ],
            [
              106.707923201947,
              10.539230085503078
            ],
            [
              106.75196848603105,
              10.514232576383892
            ],
            [
              106.79601377011508,
              10.539230085503078
            ],
            [
              106.7960209392707,
              10.589231196662963
            ],
            [
              106.76782493975878,
              10.605234887615962
            ],
            [
              106.76111674178632,
              10.601428713580317
            ],
            [
              106.76111586436221,
              10.595343333584946
            ],
            [
              106.71706253230332,
              10.570345841048965
            ],
            [
              106.70791799658124,
              10.575534789370789
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "temp": 28.0,
        "defaultUnit": "Â°C"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              106.74952463777162,
              10.594851453114759
            ],
            [
              106.76782493975878,
              10.605234887615964
            ],
            [
              106.76111783947686,
              10.609041752489026
            ],
            [
              106.76111674178633,
              10.601428713580317
            ],
            [
              106.74952463777162,
              10.594851453114759
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

[Here is the result I want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N19o0.png)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
heatMapLayer = new GeoJsonLayer(googleMap, new JSONObject(airMapGeoJsonLayer.geoJson));
  GeoJsonPolygonStyle style = heatMapLayer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
  style.setStrokeColor(airMapGeoJsonLayer.strokeColor);
  style.setStrokeWidth(airMapGeoJsonLayer.strokeWidth);
  style.setFillColor(airMapGeoJsonLayer.fillColor);
  heatMapLayer .addLayerToMap();
```

or you can try this too

```
GeoJsonPolygonStyle polyStyle = layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
polyStyle.setFillColor(FILL_GREY);
polyStyle.setStrokeColor(STROKE_GREY);
polyStyle.setStrokeWidth(4f);
```

Comment: It still can't fill color in polygon. I edited sample GeoJson data in questions.Thank you!

Comment: Please remove the intersecting line which you are adding near polygon

Comment: I have a problem in removing intersecting line in data. So I tried to fill in color polygon with extra lines in android